# Missing argument in the proof of the closedness of the graph of a morhpism between algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am following a proof of the following statements: if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of varieties (say, quasi-projective), then the graph of $f$, i.e. the subset $\Gamma_f:=\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{id}_X\times Y)\subseteq X\times Y$ is a closed subvariety of $X\times Y$, such that the co-restriction of  $\operatorname{id}_X\times Y$ yields an isomorphism. In the proof, the author takes $\{V_j\}$ an open affine cover of $Y$ and then $\{U_{ij}\}$ an open affine cover of each of the $f^{-1}(V_j)$. Then they proceed to show that if $f_{ij}:U_{ij}\to V_j$ denotes the restricted and corestricted morphism, then $\Gamma_{f_{ij}}=\Gamma_f\cap(U_{ij}\times V_j)$. Up until this point I can follow the argument. However, it is then said that in order to prove that $\Gamma_f$ is closed, it suffices to prove that each of the $\Gamma_{f_{ij}}$ is closed; i.e. the problem is reduced to the affine case. However, to me this would oly prove that $\Gamma_{f}$ is locally closed. Is there a quick argument that deduces closedness from locally closedness? Or is there a something substantially missing from the argument?

**Disclaimer:** I only yet know the classical approach to algebraic geometry, and not the modern, scheme theoretic approach

Comment: This is just point set topology, isn't it? If you have an open cover of a topological space and a subset whose intersection with each member of the open cover is closed, then the subset itself is also closed.

Comment: @ZhenLin, for the record I don't agree with your use of "just" in that sentence. I hope I don't come off the wrong way, but as someone trying to learn algebraic geometry if someone tells me my question is just topology I tend to interpret that I'm supposed to know all the topology. Since I don't know all the topology, it just makes me not want to ask questions.

Comment: @Moisés I read "just topology" as an attempt to assuage the concerns raised in the OP's disclaimer about not knowing the "modern ... approach" and focus our attention on the key part of the problem. We don't need any special algebro-geometric insight, either classical or modern, to figure this one out - it can be solved only with the tools of topology. Either way, your answer provides a good resolution to this problem, +1.

Answer (score 2):

To build on Zhen Lin's comment: If you have a topological space $A$ and a subset $B\subseteq A$, then it's closed iff there's an open cover $A = \bigcup U_i$ such that $B\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$. One way to see this is that the complement of $B$ is the union of the open sets $U_i\setminus B$, so it's open.

There's a similar way to check whether $B$ is locally closed that might be the cause of your confusion. If you can find a covering $B \subseteq \bigcup U_i$ where $U_i$ is open in $A$ and $B\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$, then $B$ is locally closed. The difference is that here $\bigcup U_i$ might not cover $A$.

Note that the $U_{ij}$'s do cover $X\times Y$ in this case.